# Cannot find C++ library when linking, error compliling the `boost::program_options` example

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am trying to compile the [multiple_sources.cpp](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/program_options/example/multiple_sources.cpp) to compile on my computer. I am running Xubuntu Lucid Lynx fully updated.

It will compile without issue with `g++ -c multiple_sources.cpp` but when I try to link and make an exectuable with `g++ multiple_sources.o` I get:

```
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x15a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::add_options()'
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)'
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)'
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x1af): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x1eb): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
multiple_sources.cpp:(.text+0x252): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
...
```

*et cetera ad nauseum*.

I do have the library installed:

```
>ls -l /usr/lib/libboost_program_options*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 640800 2010-03-31 21:19 /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 2010-04-09 00:57 /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a     -> libboost_program_options.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 2010-04-09 00:57 /usr/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.40.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34 2010-04-09 00:57 /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.40.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 289336 2010-03-31 21:19 /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.40.0
```

After reading the g++ man page, I have also tried:

- `g++ -llibboost_program_options multiple_sources.cpp`
- `g++ -llibboost_program_options.a multiple_sources.cpp`
- `g++ -llibboost_program_options.so multiple_sources.cpp`
- and all of the above with `-L/usr/lib` *before* the `-l`

They all fail with a variation on:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_program_options.so
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `-l` param is wrong; get rid of the `lib` pre-fix and use `-lboost_program_options`.

The linker expects all libraries to begin with `lib`, and for you to leave that off when specifying the library.

You could also include the full path to the library in the list of files, without `-l` (e.g. `g++ multiple_sources.cpp /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so`), but for system libraries, it's better to follow convention; they aren't always installed in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: That's right. Confusingly, the linker expects all libraries to begin with `lib`, and for you to leave that off when specifying the library.

Comment: @Mike
Thank you! I was just about to ask why that was. Now is this required? Is there someway of overriding that? I ask out of curiousity now.

Comment: @ArtB: I think you could also include the full path to the library in the list of files, without `-l` (e.g. `g++ multiple_sources.cpp /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so`). But for system libraries it's better to follow convention; they aren't always installed in `/usr/lib`.