# How to link to the C math library with CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

How do I add the `math` library to my CMake file? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639775/clion-cmake-how-to-add-library-so) references adding a [target link library](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/472180), yet I am not too familiar with C. An [Additional post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-to-add-linker-or-compile-flag-in-cmake-file) - Could someone please demonstrate an example. [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) I am using C and I receive an `undefined reference to 'pow'` with the pow method of the math header.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(CSCI-E-28-Unix-Linux-Systems-Programming)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    CMakeLists.txt
    getchar.c
    main.cpp
        hw0
    more01.c)

#target_link_libraries(<math.h> m)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
add_executable(getchar getchar.c)
add_executable(more01 more01.c)
add_executable(argu print_all_arguments.c)
add_executable(chars chars.c)
add_executable(ch4 ch4.c)
```

Comment: Why do you set CXX flags? These are for C++, not C. And you have not defined the language for your project, should be `enable_language(C)`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Many mathematical functions (`pow`, `sqrt`, `fabs`, `log` etc.) are declared in `math.h` and [require the library `libm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions#libm) to be linked. Unlike `libc`, which is automatically linked, `libm` is a separate library and often [requires explicit linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033898/2799037). [The linker presumes all libraries to begin with `lib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355372/cannot-find-c-library-when-linking-error-compliling-the-boostprogram-optio#comment3483942_3355464), so to link to `libm` you link to `m`.

You have to use it like `target_link_libraries(ch4 m)` to link `libm`to your target. The first argument must be a target. Thus it must be used after `add_executable(ch4 ch4.c)` like:

```
add_executable(ch4 ch4.c)
target_link_libraries(ch4 m)
```

Comment: It's surprising this isn't needed for Cygwin on Windows. But sadly is required on *nix.

Comment: Can you write out the full correct answer? Is `m` a placeholder? or is it just common knowledge that `math.c` is in a library called `m`? Or is it declared in a way that I don't fathom in the script above?

Comment: Awesome, I get it now. I linked to a question that I had asked earlier about how "libm" becomes just "m" just for completeness.

Comment: With MSVC this results in the following build error: `[CMake] LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'm.lib'`

Comment: I am trying to build `GLFW` from source and there is no line `add_executable` in `CMakeLists.txt`. What should I do?

Comment: This isn't a platform-independent/compiler-independent solution.

Comment: @einpoklum You are right. You might want to test if `-lm` is needed and add it conditionally.

Answer (score 12):

For various targets it's a good idea to test if adding a library is needed or not and if so where it's located of how it's named. Here's one way to do it:

```
:
include(CheckLibraryExists)

CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(m sin "" HAVE_LIB_M)                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                         
if (HAVE_LIB_M)                                                                                                                          
    set(EXTRA_LIBS ${EXTRA_LIBS} m)                                                                                                      
endif (HAVE_LIB_M)

:
//More tests & build-up of ${EXTRA_LIBS}
:

add_executable(ch4 ch4.c)
target_link_libraries(ch4 PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

For targets where `libm` is part of `libc`, the above test should fail, i.e. `${EXTRA_LIBS}` will miss it and `target_link` will not try to add.

Comment: And is there no platform on which we need to link against a math library, and that library is not named `m`? Also, see comment regarding @MichaelAmbrus' answer - sometimes libm exists, but is still redundant.

Answer (score 10):

I am frankly a bit surprised that this kind of question still doesn't have a proper answer for [Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/features/small.html). These days, the recommended (and portable) approach is this:

```
find_library(MATH_LIBRARY m)
if(MATH_LIBRARY)
    target_link_libraries(MyTarget PUBLIC ${MATH_LIBRARY})
endif()
```

Comment: This is super-convenient and easy, although it does produce an unnecessary link on macOS, due to libm being bundled into libc on macOS, but libm is still available separately too. Still, this is probably of little consequence, and it'll catch any case where it might need to be linked in manually. More portable than just checking if OS = Linux?